# How to get auto_increment id without insert in SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

As I know the command to find the AUTO_INCREMENT Value in SQL Server:

```
SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = DatabaseName
  AND TABLE_NAME = TableName;
```

But if I insert that following command to SQL Server Management Studio, it results in an error

> Invalid Column Name "AUTO_INCREMENT"

How to get `AUTO_INCREMENT` id without insert data to the table in SQL Server Management Studio?

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do?  This most certainly is not the right way to do it.

Comment: I am trying to get new id of the table which has an id column that generated with auto_increment. I've red this from another thread a command to get that new id but in phpmyadmin sql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the current identify value for a particular table, you can use [`ident_current()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ident-current-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
SELECT IDENT_CURRENT(N'SchemaName.TableName')
```

Comment: I put database name and table name inside ident_current. But still producing an error (Invalid column name 'TestDB')

Comment: @Marfin.F It should be the schema name and table name. Try this instead - leave the single quotes - just replace `dbo.TableName` with your schema/table: `SELECT IDENT_CURRENT(N'dbo.TableName')`

Comment: @MaxSzczurek It is working as expected! Thank you very much Max! Would you like to give your comment as the answer of my thread? So I can tick it as accepted answer of my thread.

Comment: @Marfin.F This answer should be marked as the correct one. Glad you found your answer!

Comment: This is still the correct answer, you should mark as such.

Comment: @theMayer Yeah I did! Thank you for the suggestion